# data-src Attribute for jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have noticed that the 'data-src' Attribute does not work within Expression Engine which makes using some jQuery plug-ins impossible. Does anyone know why this is and how it can be overcome?

Comment: It's most likely something to do with your template code. Can you post a use example?

Comment: I just used 'data-src' on my most recent project. Since you are concluding the issue is EE, can I assume you've tested and have it working outside of EE?

Comment: Please update your post with some code samples and let us know what you expect to happen vs what is actually happening.

Comment: No problem let me try a few more tests and will come back to you ... thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

'data-src' does work in EE templates. I used it on a recent project without issues.